# Java - Factorial Base Conversion

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, factorial

I am relatively new to programming, but I am trying to write a program that converts a number from base 10 to factorial base in order to assist me with a more challenging problem. Factorial base represents a number as the sum of factorials; for instance, 19 (base 10) = 301 (base factorial), because 3*3!+0*2!+1*1!=19. You can see a better explanation than mine at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial_number_system. What is the simplest way of accomplishing this for a number you can input? So far, I have been able to simply print the factorial of every number less than 10:

```
for (int base = 1; base < 10; base++){
    int factorial = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < base; i++){
        factorial = factorial*i;}
    System.out.println(factorial);}
```

I am sure I am making numerous beginner mistakes; but I greatly appreciate any help you can give me for this. Thank you for your time, and for any assistance you can provide.

Comment: why are you using tild(~) sign?

Comment: @VishalK I think he just wanted to "highlight" the error parts.

Comment: There is also the wrong `;` after `for` loop.

Comment: first things first, no tildes will be accepted

Comment: @talnicolas yeah i got that.. @matthew Tyler you should remove  semicolon (;) that you had put at the end of `for` loop statements..

Comment: Sorry about the tildes, I couldn't figure out any other way of highlighting the errors. They aren't in the actual code. Also, the semicolon was a typo. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int base = 1; base < 10; base++);{
```

You shouldn't have a semicolon between the for statement and the open brace.  The compiler is interpreting it as if you meant

```
for (...) { /* empty block */ }
{ // new, unrelated block
  ...
}
```

For the actual implementation, you can look to the Wikipedia article:

> For instance, one can convert a number into factorial representation
>   producing digits from right to left, by repeatedly dividing the number
>   by the place values (1, 2, 3, ...), taking the remainder as digits,
>   and continuing with the integer quotient, until this quotient becomes
>   0.

So something like (untested, psuedocodey)...

```
int number = 463;
int radix = 1;
String result = ""; // prob use int[] or list in real life?

while (number > 0) {
   int div = number / radix;
   int remainder = number % radix;
   result = remainder + result;
   number = div;
   ++radix;
}
```

Comment: I should have noticed that. Sorry for the simple mistake. Do you have any thoughts on the actual factorial base conversion?

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work properly... What does the "" mean?

Comment: Never-mind, I fixed it. The problem was that the place values of the digits was not distinct. Thanks for the help, and for the simple and elegant solution!

Comment: Changed the result type to a String (which it was in my head).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public int convertToFactorial(int x10){
    int length = String.valueOf(x10).length();
        String[] vals = String.valueOf(x10).split("");

        int result = 0;
        for (int base = 1; base < length + 1; base++){
            int factorial = 1;
            for (int i = vals.length - base; i > 0; i--){
                factorial = factorial*i;
            }
            result += Integer.parseInt(vals[base]) * factorial;
        }
        System.out.println(result);
     return result;
}
```

P.s. look at java code convention ant language structures, you shouldn't write ; after loop defenition.

Comment: I should have noticed that. Sorry for the simple mistake. Do you have any thoughts on the actual factorial base conversion?